# how can I manually create a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the most simple terms how do I manually create a pandas dataframe without using a dictionary, list or array. I can create the columns but for some reason I cannot manually enter data

This is the initial dictionary which was created, however I can seem to access and map individual values:

```
resource = {'<Invalid Value':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        '<Not Defined>':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Chipper':{'Chipper Required':{'EE_1410_0045':'13'}},
        'Climber':{'Climbers':{'EE_1410_0030':'22'}},
        'EWP 2 Man Crew':{'Medium EWP':{'EE_1410_0010':'2'}},
        'EWP 2 Man Large':{'Large EWP':{'EE_1410_0015':'3'}},
        'EWP 3 Man Crew':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'EWP 3 Man Large':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Forestry Mulcher':{'Medium Mulcher':{'EE_1410_0070':'20'}},
        'Other - Add Note':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Slasher':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Slasher / Mulcher':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Spray Crew':{'Spray Crew':{'EE_1410_0040':'18'}}}
```

New Function

```
def crew_type1():
    df = pd.DataFrame(crew_data['CrewEquipType1'])

    df['CrewType1'] = df.CrewEquipType1.map(pd.Series(resource_table['Konect Display']))

    return df['CrewType1']
```

Comment: `for some reason I cannot manually enter data`— Give more detail, and someone can probably tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This is the syntax I am attempting to use: resource = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Crew Resource', 'Konect Equivilant', 'Display Value', 'Unique Value'],
                        data = ['<Invalid Value>','None','None','22'])

Comment: You only need ask this quiestion: have `pd.Series(resource_table['Konect Display'])` the same index than values of df.CrewEquipType1?, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: It appears that mapping needs to be referenced from a dictionary opposed to a series, which makes perfect sense as the dictionary is hashable and serves as a reference point whereas a series does not.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this:
(Please post the question with given data and required answer format in the future,
without data its very hard to figure out what OP is trying to get. Please avoid XY problem.)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

resource = { '<Not Defined>':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Chipper':{'Chipper Required':{'EE_1410_0045':'13'}},
        'Climber':{'Climbers':{'EE_1410_0030':'22'}},
        'EWP 2 Man Crew':{'Medium EWP':{'EE_1410_0010':'2'}},
        'EWP 2 Man Large':{'Large EWP':{'EE_1410_0015':'3'}},
        'EWP 3 Man Crew':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'EWP 3 Man Large':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Forestry Mulcher':{'Medium Mulcher':{'EE_1410_0070':'20'}},
        'Other - Add Note':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Slasher':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Slasher / Mulcher':{'None':{'None':'22'}},
        'Spray Crew':{'Spray Crew':{'EE_1410_0040':'18'}}
        }

k = list(resource.keys())
v = list(resource.values())

index = k
column = [ list(vv.keys())[0] for vv in v]
value1 = [ list(list(vv.values())[0].keys())[0] for vv in v]
value2 = [ list(list(vv.values())[0].values())[0] for vv in v]

df = pd.DataFrame({'column': column, 'value1': value1,'value2': value2},index=index)

print(df)
```

## output

```
                             column        value1 value2
<Not Defined>                  None          None     22
Chipper            Chipper Required  EE_1410_0045     13
Climber                    Climbers  EE_1410_0030     22
EWP 2 Man Crew           Medium EWP  EE_1410_0010      2
EWP 2 Man Large           Large EWP  EE_1410_0015      3
EWP 3 Man Crew                 None          None     22
EWP 3 Man Large                None          None     22
Forestry Mulcher     Medium Mulcher  EE_1410_0070     20
Other - Add Note               None          None     22
Slasher                        None          None     22
Slasher / Mulcher              None          None     22
Spray Crew               Spray Crew  EE_1410_0040     18
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to create one and import it from a csv file. The reason I was going to create this was I have created this initially as a dictionary that contains multiple values, which I can't seem to access and map the individual values that I wish to use as input to another dataframe

Comment: Is it possible to access and map individual values from the dictionary in the question?

Comment: @jasw I am not sure, what are the requirements. But its possible to get values from a dictionary. ` value = mydict['mykey']`

Comment: I have since created a dataframe from a csv containing what I need, however when I attempt to map the column from the new dataframe it will not replace the value as intended. Instead it returns NaN for each value. Is there a difference between mapping from a pandas series then from a dictionary?

Comment: Basically the value in column CrewEquipType1 needs to be changed to the corresponding value in the resource table dataframe